# Illegal access exception while sharing Global data

Tags: android

i want to share the global data across activities and i have followed

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

.but i am not getting how to declare it in my manifest. i am posting my manifest code, i have tried it in different ways, but still getting the error. please tell me how to resolve it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.helloandroid"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:name=".Myapp">
    <activity android:name=".AndroidtestActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

This is my main activity

public class AndroidtestActivity extends Activity
    {

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */


  public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);

    Myapp appState = ((Myapp)getApplicationContext());

   String s= appState.getState();


    et.setText(s);


}
```

}

and my Myapp class is

class Myapp extends Application {

```
  private String myState;

  public String getState(){
    return myState;
  }
  public void setState(String s){
    myState = "hello world";
  }
}
```

i am getting error in the line 
 Myapp appState = ((Myapp)getApplicationContext());

illegal access exception ,please tell me how to resolve this problem

please help me with this.

Comment: What you really want to do, i want to share the global data across activities. Can you be more specific what you ant to share

Comment: i want to share a string variable across activities and for that i am using the above link, but still i am not getting how to declare it exactly. that is my problem

Comment: What you want  to do post your code, so that reply would be fast.

Comment: pleas someone help me with this. i need it ASAP

Comment: I have found the mistake, it is my fault i have to use  Public Myapp extends application , that i did not do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge the application tags (i.e. put the android:name in the first one and delete the rest):

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:name=".MyApp">

    <activity android:name=".AndroidtestActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

Then use `getApplication()` instead of `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: thanks for ur help stefan, but still i am getting illegal class access exception. how can i resolve it please tell me. please look at my edited post of manifest

Comment: Myapp appState = ((Myapp)getApplication()); // NOT ... getApplicationContext()!